# Not able to deploy war file on jboss after cofiger swagger on Spring mvc

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jboss, swagger-ui

I am working on spring mvc project which is deploy on jboss application server.I am gong to config swagger on this project. before config swagger it's deploy on jboss server. but after config swagger deployment fail by indicating following error

```
WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./api" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.ech.api.configuration.SpringFoxConfig
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.ech.api.configuration.SpringFoxConfig
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.ech.api.configuration.SpringFoxConfig
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket from [Module \"deployment.api.war\" from Service Module Loader]"},
  "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"api.war\".deploymentCompleteService"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
      "jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa",
      "jboss.txn.service.remote",
      "jboss.xts.handlers",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.default-service-provider-registry.ejb",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.default-service-provider-registry.web",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.ejb.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.entity",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.local-query",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.timestamps",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.server.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.server.default",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.ejb.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.server.default",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.web.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.ejb.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.entity",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.local-query",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.timestamps",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.server.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.server.default",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.ejb.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.entity",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.local-query",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.timestamps",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.server.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.server.default",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.ejb.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.ejb.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.entity",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.local-query",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.timestamps",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.server.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.server.default",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.default-server",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.ejb",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.hibernate",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.server",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.group.hibernate",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.group.server",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.ejb.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.entity",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.local-query",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.timestamps",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.server.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.server.default",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.entity",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.local-query",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.timestamps",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.server.default",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.passivation",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.expiration",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.locking",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.memory",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.transaction",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.expiration",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.locking",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.memory",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.transaction",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.expiration",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.locking",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.memory",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.transaction",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.expiration",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.locking",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.memory",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.transaction",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.client-mappings",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.hibernate",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.server",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.hibernate",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.hibernate.transport",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server.transport",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.ejb",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.web",
      "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.server"
    ]
  }
}
```

my swagerConfigfile as below

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Springfox config file as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    private static final ApiInfo DEFAULT_API_INFO = null; //Swagger info

    @Bean
    public Docket api()
    {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .forCodeGeneration(Boolean.TRUE)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.ech.api.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();

    }


}
```

I have add below dependencies to pom

```
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Spring version 3.2.10.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this configuration with **swagger version 2.7.0**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()                 .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.ech.api.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
             
    }
  @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```